# Reuse function call in Javascript [Data will duplicate twin]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Code**

**HTML**

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mytab">
       <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" bankid="1" href="#test1" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-university"></i> test1</a>
      </li>
                                                                                                                    <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" bankid="2" href="#test2" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-university"></i> test2</a>
    </li>
    </ul>

<table id="table_{{$bvl['id']}}" class="table table-bordered table-striped" cellpadding="0px" width="auto" cellspacing="0px">
                                        <thead id="headD">
                                            <tr></tr>
                                            <tr></tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="dataD" runat="server"></tbody>
                                        <tfoot>
                                            <tr></tr>
                                        </tfoot>
                                    </table>
```

**Javascript**

```
 $('.mytab a').on('click', function (e) {
                var bankid = $(this).attr("bankid");
                getTableMeta(bankid);
            })

//get column data
function getTableMeta(bankid) {
    table          = "";
    ColumnData     = "";
    EditRowData    = [];
    mdataArray     = [];
    isEditAllState = false;
    defaultcol     = "";

    $('#table_'+bankid+' thead tr:first-child th').remove();
    $('#table_'+bankid+' thead tr:nth-child(2) th').remove();
    $('#table_'+bankid+' thead tr:first-child td').remove();
    $('#table_'+bankid+' thead tr:nth-child(2) td').remove();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{route('getcolumn')}}",
        data: {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            ColumnData   = data.Column;
            var inputype = "";
            $.each(data.Column, function (index, element) {
                //title
                $('#table_'+bankid+' thead tr:first-child').append($('<th>', {
                    text: element.Name
                }));

                //insert
                if (data.Insertable == true) {
                    if (element.Editable == true) {
          
                        if(element.Name == 'in' || element.Name == 'out'){
                            inputype = 'number';
                        }else if(element.Name == 'time'){
                            inputype = 'time';
                        }else{
                            inputype = 'text';
                        }

                        $('#table_'+bankid+' thead tr:nth-child(2)').append($('<th class="'+element.Name+'"><input class="'+element.Name+'Add_'+bankid+'" style="width: 99% " type="'+inputype+'" /></th>'));
                    }else{
                        $('#table_'+bankid+' thead tr:nth-child(2)').append($('<th></th>'));
                    }
                }

                mdataArray.push({ mData: element.Name, class: element.Name });
            });

            if (data.Deletable == true) {
                $('#table_'+bankid+' thead tr:first-child').append($('<th>', {
                    text: 'Action'
                }));
                mdataArray.push({ defaultContent: '<span class="deleteBtn"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>', class: 'DeleteRow' });

            }
            if (data.Insertable == true) {
                $('#table_'+bankid+' thead tr:nth-child(2)').append($('<td><span class="insertBtn"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>'
                ));
            }
            defaultcol = data.Column[0].Name;
            //once table headers and table data property set, initialize DT
            initializeDataTable(bankid);

        }
    });
}

//get row data
function initializeDataTable(bankid) {

    table = $('#table_'+bankid).DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            url: "{{route('getcolumndata')}}",
            "type": "POST",
             data: function (data) { 

                editIndexTable = -1;
                var colname;
                var sort = data.order[0].column;
                if (!data['columns'][sort]['data'] == '')
                    colname = data['columns'][sort]['data'] + ' ' + data.order[0].dir;
                //in case no sorted col is there, sort by first col
                else colname = defaultcol + " asc";
                var colarr = [];
                var colfilter, col;
                var arr = {
                    'draw': data.draw, 
                    'length': data.length,
                    'sort': colname, 
                    'start': data.start, 
                    'search': data.search.value,
                    'bankid': bankid,
                    '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                };
                //add each column as formdata key/value for filtering
                data['columns'].forEach(function (items, index) {
                    col = data['columns'][index]['data'];
                    colfilter = data['columns'][index]['search']['value'];
                    arr[col] = colfilter;
                });
                
                return arr;
            }
           
        },
        "bSortCellsTop": true,
        "orderable": false,
        "destroy": true,
        "lengthMenu": [10, 50, 100],
        "iDisplayLength": 100,
        "searching": true,
        serverSide: true, 
        "processing": true,
        "columnDefs": [{ 'targets': 1, 'visible': false }],
        aoColumns: mdataArray
    });

    //for insert button
    $("#table_"+bankid+" thead").on('click', 'tr td span.insertBtn', function (e) {
        console.log("a"); //here will console duplicate data depend on the tab user click
        insertRowData(this.parentNode.parentNode, bankid);
    });

}
```

**Question:**
I have created a tab using bootstrap nav tab. For each tab it will have **bankID**, depending on user click and will pass the **bankID** and render the datatable. Above code is work fine, but it will be facing one problem which is duplicate called. Does it mean that, if user random play and click around with the **tab 1(test1)** or **tab 2(test2)**, when they try to insert the data it will have the duplicate enter issue. I tried to **console.log** inside the **onClick** function, it will have multiple console. It will depend on how many time that user click the tab. For example, first time when they click the **tab 2(test2)** and then click **tab 1(test1)** then click **tab 2(test2)** again, it will have 2 duplicate enter. Anyone can help on this? I get stuck at this issue long time :(

Comment: can you please tell your javascript code is render through ajax or on page refresh?

Comment: @SandeepK. through ajax

Answer (score 1):

can you  please use this code before your click function.

```
$('.mytab a').off('click');
```

for Add row click

```
$("#table_"+bankid+" thead tr td span.insertBtn").off('click');

$("#table_"+bankid+" thead").on('click', 'tr td span.insertBtn', function (e) {
    console.log("a"); //here will console duplicate data depend on the tab user click
    insertRowData(this.parentNode.parentNode, bankid);
});
```

Comment: cannot, still the same.

Comment: you have set all click function to off where you have use. If  your jquery or javascript code is loaded by ajax.

Comment: can provide some example ya?

Comment: like $('.mytab a').off('click');

Comment: by using this function previous clicks is cleared.

Comment: seems like still duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you just remove "thead row", you must remove tbody rows or create another table for every tabs.